# NSXmlParser iPhone sdk parsesing data problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, nsxmlparser

I have am parsing some data from rss but some of that data is being parsed partially so tried to append string but it is not working here is some code:

```
-(id)loadXmlByURL:(NSString *)url{
titles = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:URL];
parser.delegate = self;

[parser parse];

return self;
}


-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *) elementName namespaceURI:  (NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *) attributeDict{
 if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"])


{
currentTitle = [Titles alloc];
titles = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

}
```

}

```
 -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *) parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
   namespaceURI: (NSString *) namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *) qName


 {
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
     currentTitle.title = currentNodeContent;
     NSLog(@"%@",currentNodeContent);

 }
```

}

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSMutableString *)string{


 NSMutableString *st = [string mutableCopy];
 if (!currentNodeContent) {
     // init the ad hoc string with the value     
     currentNodeContent = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
 } else {
     // append value to the ad hoc string    

     [currentNodeContent appendString:string
      ];
 }
     currentNodeContent = [[st stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]mutableCopy];

 }
```

Comment: What do you mean "it is not working"? Post some sample input. Post some sample output. Post error messages.

Comment: so for example data is "This is a test" the out put will be just "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am reading your code correctly then the line

```
 currentNodeContent = [[st stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]mutableCopy];
```

will always overwrite the work you are doing in the `if (!currentNodeContent) {` line.

so your code may be parsing the string correctly, but regardless, it always overrwites with the trimmed string.